# Sitecore Item Access Rights

Tags: sitecore

I want to check if a sitecore item has any access rights applied or not so I am thinking of checking if the security field has a value i.e

```csharp
item.Fields["__Security"].Value
```

Is this is the correct way of checking if an item has access rights or Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the __Security Field are the rights stored.

You can use: `item.Security.GetAccessRules();`

```
var accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
if (accessRules != null)
{
    foreach (var rule in accessRules)
    {
        var name = rule.Account.Name;
        var comment = rule.AccessRight.Comment;
        var permiss = rule.SecurityPermission;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing feels more more API-ish

```csharp
foreach(Role role in RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles())
{
    bool hasReadAccess= itemUnderTest.Security.CanRead(role);
}
```

In fact, take a look at all the methods of `Item.Security`

Comment: I can check the access rights against user or role but In my case I just need to know if there are an access rights applied or not, Is the code I mentioned is the right way to check?

Comment: Then as Jan rightly says - item.Security.GetAccessRules()